# WPF comboBox Arrow Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm doing a wpf project and inside my application i have a combobox.Can i know any simple way to change the dropDown arrow color? I found the [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) here, but its too complicate. Anyone can help me out?

p/s: i'm a newbie

combobox example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the arrow is just linked to a system resource, I believe there's no way to change it other than redoing the entire template like you see in your linked article. It seems complicated, but it's not so bad, especially if you have Blend (just because Blend makes it easy to pull out the current template to edit it).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Fill="White"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```